Почему не отображаются элементы страниц, а пишет communitytoolkit.mvvm.input.relaycommand?

Что нужно сделать чтобы исправить?
    namespace MyWallet.ViewModel

{
internal class MainViewModel : ViewModedBase

{
    private Page CashAccPage = new CashAcc();
    private Page InfoChartsPage = new InfoCharts();
    private Page MainMenuPage = new MainMenu();

    private Page _CurPage = new MainMenu();

    public Page CurPage
    {
        get => _CurPage;
        set => Set(ref _CurPage, value);
    }

    public ICommand OpenMainPage
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(()=> CurPage = MainMenuPage);
        }
    }
    public ICommand OpenCashAccPage
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() => CurPage = CashAccPage);
        }
    }
    public ICommand OpenInfoChartsPage
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() => CurPage = InfoChartsPage);
        }
    }
}

}
namespace MyWallet.ViewModel

{
internal abstract class ViewModedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged

{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void onPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
    protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        onPropertyChanged(PropertyName);
        return true;
    }
}

}
И собственно сами кнопки которые должны переключать страницы
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent">
                <Button Content="Главная" Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LeftMenu}" Command="{Binding OpenMainPage}"/>
                <Button Content="Счета" Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LeftMenu}" Command="{Binding OpenCashAccPage}"/>
                <Button Content="Графики" Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LeftMenu}" Command="{Binding OpenInfoChartsPage}"/>
                <Button Content="Валюта" Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LeftMenu}"/>
                <Button Content="Регулярные платежи" Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LeftMenu}"/>
                <Button Content="Настройки" Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LeftMenu}"/>
            </StackPanel>


Очевидно, вы привязались не к тому, что должно быть, вот вам и сделало привязанноеСвойство.ToString(), что по умолчанию выводит название типа. К чему конкретно там привязываться вам надо - на этот вопрос должны ответить вы сами, ибо мы не видим вашего кода, и не знаем что у вам там и как сделано.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Добавил свою реализацию

Подумайте пожалуйста хоть немножко. Вот у вас вопрос какой? Если упростить, то "Почему пишет СommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.RelayCommand, а не выдает страницу?", я вам говорю "вы привязываетесь не к тому свойству". Включаем логику и...., что должно быть в вопросе? Правильно, тот элемент, который отвечает за вывод страницы, который привязан к свойству, а также само свойство. У вас это есть в вопросе? Кнопки вижу, свойства, наверно, тоже. Но где тот, кто отображает вам этот текст? Где правая часть с картинки? Самое важное вы вдруг забыли...

И правда забыл самое важное. В этом и была проблема. Спасибо
